# bash script awk with passing variable and if statement

Tags: bash, variables, if-statement, awk

I am writing a bash script using awk with variable passing in AIX powerpc machine.
The code written works fine after I read some questions & answers in this site. :)

Now, I'd like to add if statement in my bash script and I got awk syntax errors.
My requirement (see my script below):
- if awk pattern matching is true, print $0 
- else print "transaction: p value not found."

Content of trans.txt

```
bash-4.2$ cat trans.txt

10291413
8537353
8619033
8619065
8625705
```

Could someone help me please. Thank you.

content of getDetail.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

sysDir="/var/syslog-ng/TEST/STS"
syslogFile="DPSTSLog2014-10-22T09.log"
pattern="Latency"

filename=$1
while read f; do
  concatPattern="$f.*$pattern"
  awk -v p="$concatPattern" '$0 ~ p {print $0}' $sysDir/$syslogFile
done < $filename
```

run command execution below

```
./getDetails.sh trans.txt
```

result

```
2014-10-22T09:15:53+11:00,10.16.198.50,info,latency,[info] xmlfirewall(ws-TrustValidate): trans(10291413): Latency:   0   0   0   0  14  14   0  14   0   0   0  14   0   0   0   0
2014-10-22T09:15:38+11:00,10.16.198.50,info,latency,[info] xmlfirewall(ws-TrustValidate): trans(8619033): Latency:   0   0   0   0  73  73   0  73   0   0   0  73   0   0   0   0
2014-10-22T09:18:04+11:00,10.16.198.50,info,latency,[info] xmlfirewall(ws-TrustValidate): trans(8625705): Latency:   0   0   0   0  13  13   0  13   0   0   0  13   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: `{print $0}` could become `{print $0;next} {do other thing}`

Comment: Thanks for the speedy comment, Mark.  I tried that it did not work as expected.

Comment: `{print $0;next} {print "transaction: p value not found."}`

Comment: I updated my script as above. The output:  "transaction: p value not found" was repeated for 4000 lines I guess that's number of $sysDir/$syslogFile line of record.  I noticed the awk syntax is quite temperamental in bash / AIX flavor. That's why I cant make the simple if / else statement to work.

Comment: What is in `trans.txt` and where is `$filename` set?

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v p="$concatPattern" '
    $0 ~ p {print $0; found=1}
    END   {if (! found) print "transaction: p value not found"}
' $sysDir/$syslogFile
```

Comment: I think we got there in the end :-)

Comment: The answer does not meet my expectation. I did some troubleshooting with my above code and make a conclusion (I might be wrong on this, please confirm). The awk find match statement I used above will only execute a true boolean value, therefore ; found=1 never get executed for unmatch eg. false boolean. The END statement becomes useless. I have tested it myself.   What I meant was awk cannot tell me when the pattern does not match, it simply do nothing.

Comment: @ChristinaLiu maybe you can change slightly one of your requirements, so that Glenn can write `print "transaction:",p,"not found"`, i.e., a more informative warning.

Comment: Do you need awk to tell you which lines did not match the pattern, or which files did not contain the pattern?

Comment: No, I didn't change the original requirement. The solution provided above can not spit out "transaction: p not found" for unmatch pattern.

Comment: of course it can. What does this show on your system: `awk -v p=foobar '$0~p {print;f=1} END {if (!f) print p, "not found"}' /etc/passwd` then try again with `-v p=root` or some user that is in /etc/passwd

Comment: I still want you to answer the question: do you want to print the "not found" message for each **line** that does not match, or do you want to print "not found" if the pattern is not in the **file**? My answer addresses the latter.

Comment: My logic is: if a match exists, set found to true. In the end block, if **not found** then print "not found"